# Dividing slider values into range segments

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Like most developers, my Math skills are poorly inadequate.

I have a slider with values 0 to ~ and the first half of the slider should run through the scale 0-10 whilst the second half of the slider should run through the values 11-~.

The solution I have is very procedural and looks as follows:

```
var sliderPercent = timeSlider.sliderPosition;

// What number on the scale of 0 to hoursMax does our % equal?
var position = (this.options.hoursMax / 100) * sliderPercent;

var newMin = 0;
var newMax = 10 * 2; // new max is 20, so half way is 10.

var oldRange = (this.options.hoursMax - this.options.hoursMin);
var newRange = (newMax - newMin); // new range is 0-20

if(sliderPercent > 50) {
    newRange = (this.options.hoursMax + newMax - this.options.hoursMin);
    position -= newMax;
}

var newValue =  ((position * newRange) / oldRange);
```

As with all things, there's surely a much better way to do this. Something involving log and exp and those lovely Math functions.

It would also be nice if I could easily divide my slider into sections with different ranges. Perpahs 50% - 75% will be 11 - 50 and the last quater 50 - ~. I'm looking for an understanding of how to build a more general solutiin.

Comment: What do you mean by "~"?  I also get the feeling that you don't want a linear scale for this slider (unless ~ = 20), but I can't tell what you do want.

Comment: I'm using ~ to represent infinity.

Comment: Meaning, some arbitrary end value. Let's call it 60.

Comment: ... OK.  60 != infinity, BTW, so telling us that was... confusing.

Comment: 60 not being equal to infinity. A revelation! My point is, the end value can be anything, it's not relevant to my question. My question is about the first half of the slider being in the range 0-10 whilst the second half incrementing through the range 11-"some other big number". I hope that's not confusing for you.

Comment: What that endpoint is, and in particular whether or not it is finite, is highly relevant to the *answer* to your question.

Comment: @Jamie: will the endpoint be updated/changed? It's not really clear how you're going to use this slider (i.e. I don't see why you are talking about infinity if you actually have a known end value).

Comment: The end value will change. The slider indicates a number of hours and on some pages the max hours will be 20, on another page it will be 160. The end point is always represented by `this.options.hoursMax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking at a way to split the slider into multiple sections for mapping into a result value.

I.e. something like this would work for linear ranges:

```
// define sections as a sparse array holding slider ranges:
var sections = [];
sections[50] = 10;        // map [0, 50>  to [0, 10>
sections[60] = 20;        // map [50, 60>  to [10, 20>
sections[70] = 100;       // map [60, 70>  to [20, 100>
sections[80] = 500;       // map [70, 80>  to [100, 500>
sections[90] = 1000;      // map [80, 90> to [500, 1000>
sections[100] = 10000;    // map [90, 100> to [500, 1000>

function mapPercentToValue(percent) {

    var previousKey = 0;
    var sectionStart = 0;
    var sectionEnd = 0;

    for (var key in sections) {
        sectionEnd = sections[key];
        if (key >= percent) {
            break;
        }
        sectionStart = sectionEnd;
        previousKey = key;
    }

    return (percent - previousKey) 
        / (key - previousKey) 
        * (sectionEnd - sectionStart) + sectionStart;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Groo. From my initial testing, this does exactly what I want.

Comment: My point earlier about the max value being irrelevant holds well here since `sections[100]` can simply `= this.options.hoursMax`. Thanks for this Groo.